# How to use newer blender addons in older versions?

Tags: add-on

I know this is a stupid question to ask but is there any ways to use newer blender addons in older blender versions like Blender 2.79. I am using blender 2.79 because my computer is not capable with later versions. If it is possible in some ways, please let me know.

I have also done some research but found nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there can be a single answer to this; it depends on the specific Add On, and what features of Blender its authors assumed were present. Depending on which features they relied on, the code for the Add On may require no changes, small changes, or dramatic changes, in order to work in an earlier Blender version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a stupid question.  Depending on the add-on, there are three cases:

1. The add-on has an available older version that will work with the version of Blender that you are interested in, in this case 2.79.  This will be true of a few of the more popular add-ons, but it can sometimes be hard to find versions that work with older versions of Blender.  Also, of course, the older version of the add-on won't have all of the features of the newer version.
2. The add-on "just works".  The add-on might have been written for the older version of Blender, and the developer might have updated it in ways that maintain compatibility; or simply not used any features that have changed between releases.  But again, there's a chance that the add-on might have features that only work in newer versions of Blender.  This is usually because the feature relies on a later feature in Blender itself.
3. You're simply out-of-luck.  The add-on uses features that aren't available in the older version of Blender and can't really be modified to work with older versions.  3.0 add-ons that use Geometry Nodes Fields are an example of such add-ons.

If the add-on was shipped with Blender, then finding all of this out is simply a matter of checking your Preferences to see if the add-on is in the version of Blender you want to use.

If the add-on is from a third party, first check their web site to see if they have copies of their old version and then search the internet to see if anyone still has a copy.

Comment: Thanks Marty Fouts and NeverConvex for replying to my post. Now I have a clear idea of blender addons.